# Is it possible to create Python-like dictionaries with LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: python, libreoffice-calc, dictionary

Considering that Python dictionaries associate key elements to value elements:

```
dictionary = {
    "keyOn"e: "valueOne",
    "keyTwo": "valueTwo",
    "keyThree": "valueThree",
    0: 4,
    1: 3.75,
    2: 3.5
}
```

And considering that this allows to recall values through keys:

```
dictionary["keyOne"]
>>> 'valueOne'
dictionary[0]
>>> 4
```

I am wondering if it is possible to do something similar with LibreOffice Calc.

In particular, is it possible to insert `0` in a cell, for instance, and then make the `4` value appear into the nearest cell on the same row?
If yes, can you suggest functions that allow this?

Comment: Do you mean [VLOOKUP](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#VLOOKUP)?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, maybe, but I am not properly familiar with functions, in general. I am going to test it now. Thank you in advance for your suggestion.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, it works! Just another question for a little improvement, if possible: when I copy the formula and I paste it to the next cell, all the coordinates are incremented by one, and so the reference to the array is not correct. Is it possible to increment just the first variable, that is `SearchCriterion`, and keep `Array` constant when copying and pasting?

Comment: You need to use absolute references. https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Addresses_and_References,_Absolute_and_Relative